# Optimize median measure in dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, azure-analysis-services, daxstudio

I have the below median measure that I am using in my report, but when I publish to power bi service, I get this error message "Resources Exceeded This visual has exceeded the available resources. Try filtering to decrease the amount of data displayed". Resource Governing: This query uses more memory than the configured limit. The query — or calculations referenced by it — might be too memory-intensive to run. Either reach out to your Analysis Services server administrator to increase the per-query memory limit or optimize the query so it consumes less memory. More details: consumed memory 11753 MB, memory limit 10240 MB."

I have increase the capacity in both AAS and Power BI but still getting same error.
The measure is

CALCULATE ( MEDIANX( FILTER('rep vFact', 'rep vFact'[loanAmount] > 0), ( 'rep vFact'[loanAmount])) )

Please, how do I optimze this measure to be more efficient. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEDIANX is an iterator and FILTER is another iterator. Also You are iterating the full table('rep vFact') which is not a good practice. I will recommend 3 measures. Please test them and give me feedback.

1st Measure:

```
Measure_01 =
MEDIANX (
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'rep vFact' ), 'rep vFact'[loanAmount] > 0 ),
    'rep vFact'[loanAmount]
)
```

2nd Measure

```
Measure_02 =
MEDIANX (
    CALCULATETABLE ( 'rep vFact', 'rep vFact'[loanAmount] > 0 ),
    'rep vFact'[loanAmount]
)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I will test and let you know.

Comment: I tested these measures, measure_01 is showing a constant value irrespective of my slicer selection(like year), however the value is not correct.
measure_02 and measure_03 are showing same values when I make a slicer selection but the value is not correct. thanks

Comment: Ok. thank you for the feedback. I think maybe we should put calculate in front of 2nd and 3rd measures. I updated it. Please test it.

Comment: No effect with the changes

Comment: Hello, I updated the measures. 1st measure is not so different. I think 2nd measure will do the job fine.

Comment: Thanks Ozan, measure_02 is returning the correct values but still a little bit slow.
Thanks for your help, I appreciate it a lot

Comment: Hello @gregeal I am pleased to hear that It is working. let's stay in touch, and try to find better one. If possible , you can share dax studio performance results. I can see better(Server timings, Formula Engine, Storage engine workloads etc...) Stay safe be well.